# Iterate differently through first and other subarrays of array in handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have an array of arrays of json objects, where the first element has different keys than the rest and I would like to iterate differently in the first subarray than the rest.

My array looks like this:

```
array = [
          [{id: 0, title: "test", image: "link"},
           {id: 1, title: "othertest", image: "link2"},
           {id: 2, title: "otherothertest",image: "link3"}],

          [{id: 0, title: "tsas", category_id: 1},
           {id: 1, title: "askd", category_id: 1},
           {id: 2, title: "aksda", category_id: 1}},

         [{id: 0, title: "askda", category_id: 2},
          {id: 1, title: "sadkaw", category_id: 2}
        ]
```

And I'd like to iterate through it using different HTML for the first and the other two like so:

```
{{#each subarray}}
  {{#if @first}}
    {{#each first}}
      <p> {{first.id}}</p>
      <a href="index.html?id={{first.id}}&type=subcategories"><p>  {{first.title}}</p></a>
      <a href="index.html?id={{first.id}}&type=subcategories"><img src="{{first.img_url}}"></a>
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <!--something else-->
{{/each}}
```

Now the error I'm getting is `if doesn't match each`.

Are there any good options I can use?

Thank you all for any advice,
HMcJ

Described in the post above, I'd like to see if there's a way to "seperate" the first element, or exclude others in the loop.

Comment: I would recommend against this data structure. If the type of objects in the first array are different from those in the rest, then these should be in separate arrays. That will make everything much simpler in your template.

Comment: @76484 If I separated it into two arrays, can I send them both in the same handlebars template?

Comment: Certainly! You would pass an object to your template. For example: `{ categories: [], images: [] }`.

Comment: If I use this, how should I make the {{#each}} statement for each sub-object?

I tried {{#each categories}} but it didn't work.

Comment: Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/o6a2xjdq/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up to:

```
{{#each this}}
  {{#if @first}}
    {{#each this}}
      <p>{{id}}</p>
      <a href="index.html?id={{id}}&type=subcategories"><p>{{title}}</p></a>
      <a href="index.html?id={{id}}&type=subcategories"><img src="{{image}}"></a>
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    {{#each this}}
      <div>id:{{id}} | Title: {{title}} | category_id: {{category_id}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cherry-dch25m?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) d {description: undefined, fileName: undefined, lineNumber: 6, endLineNumber: 6, message: "if doesn't match each - 6:23", …}

It's still the same error, from what I gather handlebars doesn't recognise that the nested loop is only on the @first element.

Comment: This solution appears to be a good one to me.

Comment: @HenryMcJonathan Added a sandbox link, it works there